# StaleElementReferenceException when I try to get window.dataLayer with Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, google-analytics, google-datalayer, selenide

I want to get gtm dataLayer events from Google Analytics on my page and check their contents after login/logout for example. I use Selenide + java in my tests
Code example without actions on page

```
open("url");
List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, String>> dataLayerEventsList = Selenide.executeJavaScript("return window.dataLayer");
        for (Map<String, String> map:dataLayerEventsList) {
            if (map.containsKey("firstKey") && map.containsKey("secondKey"))
                result.add(map);
        }
        return result;
```

When I don't do some actions on page I get events (just open the page and return window.dataLayer), but when I do some actions, F.E. click on element, setValue then when I want to get GA events in the same way I have a error in method Selenide.executeJavaScript("return window.dataLayer")

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found
```

Code example with actions on page

```
open("url");
$(By.className("login-form__select")).click();
SelenideElement login = $x("//div/../input").setValue("5645645");
SelenideElement password = $x("//div/../input").setValue("6666");
$x("//button[contains(@class,'login-form_999')]").click();
List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, String>> dataLayerEventsList = Selenide.executeJavaScript("return window.dataLayer");
        for (Map<String, String> map:dataLayerEventsList) {
            if (map.containsKey("firstKey") && map.containsKey("secondKey"))
                result.add(map);
        }
        return result;
```

How can I resolve this problem? Please, help

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException occurs when element on which trying to perform operation is nott available in the DOM. Use WebDriverWait to resolve your issue

Comment: I tried to wait and sleep about 20 sec, but it didn't help

Comment: provide your link or DOM ?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't. it's commercial

Comment: Hi,

`window.dataLayer` is the API used to *push* data and event to Google Tag Manager.
From GTM it is possible to configure Triggers that will eventually fire Google Analytics hits.

Could you be more explicit in what you are trying to achieve and the purpose of it ?
That would help providing a better answer

Comment: I want to get gtm dataLayer events from Google Analytics on my page and check their contents after login/logout for example.

Answer (score 0):

please find the element again before finding the element that you are trying to click.

What the Stale Exception basically means is that your element can't be located know as it is not in DOM know, the reason behind that is For Ex. you located an element and lets say you refreshed the page or navigated to some other page and after that you try to use that element you found before performing the action , then the Stale Element exception will be thrown .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Clicking or selecting are successful, the problem in using method executeJavaScript("return window.dataLayer") and here I don't select any element, and I don't understand why its error occurs here=(

Answer (score 0):

I found decision. Firstly, I can't get all list of window.dataLayer events because the error occurs, but, I can get window.dataLayer.lenth, and look over each event I select needed, and used try..catch with continue of course for getting around my error